# Is it suitable to store online public datasets in more than one depository?

Tags: data, data-sharing

If one has a publicly available dataset depositored in an online depository such as Zenodo or Figshare, is it suitable for the same data be stored in a separate location such as ResearchGate that can use the same DOI? I am not sure if this would count as dual publication, or if this is even valid for this type of data. This is assuming:

- The exact same datasets
- The same DOI is used for both sources i.e. no new DOIs
- The data is publically available and the depository's license reflects this

This may also be complicated if the dataset is updated in the future, as it may then need to be updated in both locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data can be considered a creative product (hence copyrightable) and if you hold copyright to it, then you can do with it pretty much as you like, so long as you don't violate any licenses that you have already given. An exclusive license given to one repository would make it improper to give another license to another, but that is unlikely.

I'm assuming that the original DOI attaches to the object itself, and not to its repository, as it should be, so that shouldn't change, though a DOI normally points to a source, which would no longer be unique. The DOI system has provision for that, but you will need to manage it.

You could, alternatively, leave various pointers around in different places to point to the original.

If you've given up copyright (say, to a publisher), then you can only do what any license entitles you to do.

If you modify/update the dataset, you might be better off treating the result as a new set, with a new DOI. Otherwise you will cause problems with citations made by others.

And note that not all datasets can be considered copyrightable.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer [in the official DOI definitions](https://www.doi.org/doi_handbook/3_Resolution.html).

> DOI resolution records can include one or more URLs, where the object
> can be located

So the different URLs must be recorded in the DOI.

If you want to update the URLs at a later point, please have a look [at the right side of this page](https://www.doi.org/) (right side of the webpage [www.doi.org](http://www.doi.org))

> Clicking on a DOI link (try this one:
> https://doi.org/10.1109/5.771073) takes you to one or more current
> URLs or other services related to a single resource. If the URLs or
> services change over time, e.g., the resource moves, this same DOI
> will continue to resolve to the correct resources or services at their
> new locations.

So in principle the same object can be referred via 2 or more URLs.

Please note that a DOI cannot be deleted, so updating URLs must and is contemplated.

For an example of versions management, have a look [at the page of SeaDataNet](https://www.seanoe.org/html/doi-versions-management.htm).